# Where can I find string escape sequences in the Ruby documentation?

Tags: ruby

I can find details on Ruby's escape sequences in "[Ruby Strings](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_strings.htm)", and "[Escape sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences)". However, where in the official Ruby docs can I find details on string escape sequences?

This question is important for people who are just learning Ruby, as understanding how to simply navigate the documentation is an initial challenge.

Comment: Why does this question deserve a down vote?

Comment: Good question, and unfortunately (imho) the SO design is such that no one can give you a definitive answer to that question if the person who downvoted doesn't offer one up. In some cases, such as this one, you can look at the reason for close votes and hypothesize that the downvote is for the same reason. If you're interested in this topic, there's a lot on meta about it.

Comment: The good news is that often times, downvotes will solicit sympathy upvotes and you'll end up net neutral in votes and positive in reputation.

Comment: @Peter Alfvin - do you have any links to good meta discussions about this? At times I feel the peer review system of SO lacks appropriate feedback mechanisms. If more tangible feedback were offered on how to improve questions (similar to peer review feedback in the academic publishing context), I believe that the quality of many questions could be improved.

Comment: Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes and the questions "linked" to it (on the right hand side of the page).

Comment: I think it's an excellent question, because I'd like to know too! There's really not much at the page linked to in the accepted answer. I'd like to know, for example, where I can find out why `puts "\123"` outputs nothing but `S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While opinions vary as to what constitutes the "official" documentation, I would offer http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings as an answer to your question.

Comment: Downvoted because the linked page does not give a list of escape sequence

Comment: I'll bet the page did have the escape sequences then.  2013 was a long time ago.

Answer (score 16):

Please see the [official documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/doc/syntax/literals.rdoc#label-Strings) (or on [ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)) which has been updated with a full list of supported escape characters:

```
\a             bell, ASCII 07h (BEL)
\b             backspace, ASCII 08h (BS)
\t             horizontal tab, ASCII 09h (TAB)
\n             newline (line feed), ASCII 0Ah (LF)
\v             vertical tab, ASCII 0Bh (VT)
\f             form feed, ASCII 0Ch (FF)
\r             carriage return, ASCII 0Dh (CR)
\e             escape, ASCII 1Bh (ESC)
\s             space, ASCII 20h (SPC)
\\             backslash, \
\nnn           octal bit pattern, where nnn is 1-3 octal digits ([0-7])
\xnn           hexadecimal bit pattern, where nn is 1-2 hexadecimal digits ([0-9a-fA-F])
\unnnn         Unicode character, where nnnn is exactly 4 hexadecimal digits ([0-9a-fA-F])
\u{nnnn ...}   Unicode character(s), where each nnnn is 1-6 hexadecimal digits ([0-9a-fA-F])
\cx or \C-x    control character, where x is an ASCII printable character
\M-x           meta character, where x is an ASCII printable character
\M-\C-x        meta control character, where x is an ASCII printable character
\M-\cx         same as above
\c\M-x         same as above
\c? or \C-?    delete, ASCII 7Fh (DEL)
```

If you find anything to add or fix, we welcome feedback and contributions via pull-request on GitHub or via our [issue tracker](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Below are some of the more common escape sequences that can appear inside of double quotes.

`\"` – double quote (`"`)

`\\` – single backslash (`\`)

`\a` – bell/alert (plays a tone)

`\b` – backspace (removes previous character, shifts cursor back one position)

`\r` – carriage return (moves cursor to beginning of line)

`\n` – newline (moves cursor to next line)

`\s` – space ( )

`\t` – tab (	)