# ruby remove ctrl-H characters

Tags: ruby, regex

On one of my log file I have the below hidden values and color ASCII codes,

```
...WAITING^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H
```

I was able to remove the color ASCII codes using below method,

```
gsub(/\e\[(\d+)(;(\d+))?m/, '')
```

but am still unable to remove that mentioned above hidden characters. Is there any way to get them rid of?

Comment: `'...WAITING^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H'.delete('/^H')`

Comment: @AlexGolubenko : No. it deletes too much : `'...WAIHTING^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H'.delete('/^H')` -> `"...WAITING"`

Comment: @EricDuminil your right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Theory

#### Backspaces ?

If the `ctrl-H` characters are backspaces :

```
puts "foo\b\b\bbar"
#=> "bar"

puts "foo\b\b\bbar".delete("\b")
#=> "foobar"
```

NOTE: `delete` is fine here, because we use it with just one character.

#### Or "^H" substring ?

If the `ctrl-H` characters are `"^H"` :

```
puts "foo^H^H^Hbar".gsub(/\^H/,'')
#=> "foobar"
```

NOTE: `delete` wouldn't work here, because it would also remove every `H` character from the strings, not just the substring `^H`. Also, using `delete("^H")` means `delete every character that isn't a 'H'`. So :

```
"foo^H^H^Hbar".delete("^H") => "HHH"
```

## Test

With :

```
bytes = [46, 46, 46, 87, 65, 73, 84, 73, 78, 71, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 91, 32, 32, 32, 79, 75, 32, 32, 32, 93, 10, 27, 91, 63, 49, 50, 108, 27, 91, 63, 50, 53, 104, 68, 111, 110, 101, 33, 10, 10]
```

We get :

```
string = bytes.map(&:chr).join
string # => "...WAITING\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b[   OK   ]\n\e[?12l\e[?25hDone!\n\n"
puts string
# [   OK   ]
# Done!
#
```

Bytes equal to `8` are backspaces, and they delete `WAITING` when displayed with `puts`.
The first alternative should work fine :

```
puts string.delete("\b")
# ...WAITING[   OK   ]
# Done!
```

NOTE: This only works on the original data, in which backspaces are byte `8`. Any copy-paste, use of `cat`, `|` or text editor might convert those to `"^H"` or other string.

Comment: Its `"^H"` not backspaces and this is what I found when I cat that file with `-e` options. Its hidden character and even if I put `^H` in gsub its not working. I think need to get the ASCII value of this hidden character and delete it. Is there way to get the ASCII value of this hidden character. 

Also the characters `"...WAITING"` also hidden one and not visible it normally and was able to view using `cat -e` only.

Comment: Okay. Could you please update your question with the result of `your_string_with_hidden_chars.each_byte.to_a`?

Comment: Here is the output,

`irb(main):001:0> str="...WAITING^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H[   OK   ]"
=> "...WAITING^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H[   OK   ]"
irb(main):002:0> str.each_byte.to_a
=> [46, 46, 46, 87, 65, 73, 84, 73, 78, 71, 94, 72, 94, 72, 94, 72, 94, 72, 94, 72, 94, 72, 94, 72, 94, 72, 94, 72, 94, 72, 91, 32, 32, 32, 79, 75, 32, 32, 32, 93]
irb(main):003:0>`

Comment: You copy-pasted this string from the log file into your irb, right? That's too late, it already removed the hidden chars. `gsub` works fine with the bytes you sent me. You could copy the log file, only keep this "WAITING" line and read it with : `File.open("your.log").each_byte.to_a`

Comment: I did copy past from `cat -e` output of log file, since there only I was to see these hidden characters. Do I need to copy past only the line that are visible normally?

Comment: Here are the details,

From vi editor I was able to see below lines,

`...WAITING^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H[   OK   ]
^[[?12l^[[?25hDone!`

In irb mode,
`irb(main):001:0> File.open("/tmp/testfile").each_byte.to_a
=> [46, 46, 46, 87, 65, 73, 84, 73, 78, 71, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 91, 32, 32, 32, 79, 75, 32, 32, 32, 93, 10, 27, 91, 63, 49, 50, 108, 27, 91, 63, 50, 53, 104, 68, 111, 110, 101, 33, 10, 10]
irb(main):002:0>`

in cat,
`# cat /tmp/testfile
[   OK   ]
Done!
#`

in cat -e,
`# cat -e /tmp/sadfsadf
...WAITING^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H[   OK   ]$
^[[?12l^[[?25hDone!$
$
#`

Comment: Thanks. You see all the `8`? Those are backspaces. The `delete("\b")` should work fine, as long as you work on the data that is directly coming from your file. Not a string that has been copied from `cat` or `vim`.

Comment: hmm its not working. I just checked on source code its `\c` . 
`"${txtdim}${txtflsh}...WAITING${txtrst}\c"`

Comment: I'm not sure what `\c` means. It could (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743964/where-can-i-find-string-escape-sequences-in-the-ruby-documentation) mean "don't output the trailing newline". I suspect all the "\b"s come from `txtrst`

Comment: In that link which you provide below is the catch,
`\cx or \C-x    control character, where x is an ASCII printable character`

basically \c will remove newline character and combine next line output with previous line

Comment: Ok it worked with `delete("\b")`. Looks like I was trying wrongly earlier. Thank you so much!